How to create .exr file with customized point light?
I want to create a illumination condition for neural network with the format of '.exr' and I want to use point light as direct light source.The example is below, I want to get the .exr file(at the bottom of left) and the chrome ball image(the main image),and I also want to change the number, color, intensity, position, etc of the point light, how can I do this with Blender Python.
To more specific，I don't know how to use the python blender api to meet my need temporarily. The image above is one of the diagrams from paper called switchlight,maybe it is because I don't read the paper carefully, I don't know whether it is a mirror ball or not.
Borrowing the py code envmap2ball, I can project a '.exr' file to a 2d ball. I just create a simple blend file here, I can get a digarm which is similar to the image in previous display. But now I don't know how to project two point light(I will change the point light into other types in the further to create various lighting) to 2d plane to create a '.exr' file in bledner.


That’s not a question, that’s a free dev labor request. Did you research this at all? It can be done, but there’s nothing you can’t find yourself quite easily in the Blender Python API Docs if you’ll go looking, except universal (I.e. off-topic) Python skills.

I don't think it's off-topic. Too broad, too vague. Liliazhen, what have you tried as far? Could you edit the question and add the code you have as far? What part of it do you struggle with? Also if it's a chrome ball, it's a mirror ball basically, so you just need equirectangular projection of the environment as the small image and then mirror ball projection of the same environment as the main image? Your shared image doesn't look like mirror ball.

I feel sorry about the stupid question I asked.Because I am a green hand of blender and I am not familiar with CG, I don't know how to use the python blender api to meet my need temporarily. The image above is one of the diagrams from paper called switchlight,maybe it is because I don't read the paper carefully, I don't know whether it is a mirror ball or not.

Borrowing the py code envmap2ball, I can project a '.exr' file to a 2d ball. I just create a simple blend file here, I can get a digram which is similar to the image in previous display.
But now I don't know how to project two point light(I will change the point light into other types  in the further to create various lighting) to 2d plane to create a '.exr' file in bledner.

@liliazhen Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Sorry, this might be a bit rude, but I suspect that this is a large scale XY problem. You seem to be trying to do something quite complex with AI at which task you don't seem to know what you are doing at all and in order to do it you think you need to do another very complex task that you also have no idea about. So, chances are: if anyone tries to help you with this complex Y problem of automating rendering, that doesn't even mean they will actually help you with the original X goal. This would make this whole situation an enormous waste of time.

In order to avoid this situation I think you should attempt to form this whole problem in a very specific way and think it through very carefully. You should read the paper carefully and then read a dozen more papers and decide what you want to do exactly.

Thanks for all you useful comments, I also feel confused about what I want and what I should do at many times, I will read the relevant paper carefully and then decide what I should do further.
